# wicket deserealization exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, wicket

i`m using Wicket with Spring context in my webapp.
I have BasePage class with field:

```
@SpringBean(name="epfc")
protected ExternalPropertiesFileConfig externalPropertiesFileConfig;
```

and All other pages is extended from this page.

Also i use KryoSerializer in my wicket:

```
KryoSerializer ser = new KryoSerializer(Bytes.megabytes(1L));
getFrameworkSettings().setSerializer(ser);
```

and AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext as rootContext in Wicket App

```
     AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    //Beans definitions (annotations)
    rootContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
    //install Spring Context for spring dependency injection
    getServletContext().setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, rootContext);
    SpringComponentInjector springComponentInjector = new SpringComponentInjector(this , rootContext, true);
    getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(springComponentInjector);
```

And here is some info from my ExternalPropertiesFileConfig class:

```
public class ExternalPropertiesFileConfig {

private Properties prop;
private IResource logo;
//constructor
public ExternalPropertiesFileConfig() {
    Plugin plugin = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("MinecraftWebService");
    File pluginDir = plugin.getDataFolder();
    loadFileToPropertiesObject(pluginDir);
    loadImgFile(pluginDir);
}
}
```

All is working good. But here is some problems:
For example i`m on HomePage now, and i click a link and redirected to LoginPage. So HomePage must be serialized. There is no problems.
But when i click BACK BUTTON IN MY BROWSER - there is some errors:
Stack Trace is too big, so it is stored here: https://hastebin.com/oduyutekiv.sql

Comment: I would suggest you to try wicketstuff-kryo2. wicketstuff-kryo uses way too old version of Kryo library. If this doesn't help too then try without Kryo, i.e. the native Java serialization. If it still breaks then create a mini app reproducing the problem and attach it to a ticket in Wicket JIRA.

Comment: Okay, thx, i tried, but the problem is not resolved:
StackTrace with kryo2 serializer: https://hastebin.com/umogowovac.sql

Comment: How i can assume - there is no problems with Serialization/Deserialization. Threre is problems to set deserialized object to Page Field using SpringComponentInjector. 
I Also tried to use or not user proxies: 
new SpringComponentInjector(this , rootContext, true);
new SpringComponentInjector(this , rootContext, false);
Default Java Serializator, Kryo, Kryo2. The problem is the same.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, i found wicketstuff-serializer-fast2 - and it`s working good.
Thx to @martin-g for help.

Default Wicket JavaSerializer - not working for me

Kryo and Kryo2 Serializers - not working for me too

WicketStuff Fast 2 Serializer - is OK, no more problems.